# Hibernate table per class hierarchy with explicit polymorphism throws can not get reflection value

Tags: hibernate, polymorphism, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting **IllegalArgumentException** while saving an dynamic entity,

I have two classes as **SuperClassImpl** and **SubClassImpl**, which are mapped using table per class hierarchy. Also, I used the explicit polymorphism to use same POJO for two different tables.

```
<class name="SuperclassImpl" polymorphism="explicit" table="super_class" mutable="true" discriminator-value="1000">
<id name='id' type='long'>
<discriminator column="data" type="int"/>
<version name='version'/>
<property name="entry"/>
<subclass name="SupclassImpl" discriminator-value="1">
    <property name="subId" column="sub_id" type="long"/>
</subclass>
```

```
<class name="SuperclassImpl" entity-name="SuperclassImplHist"  table="super_class_hist" mutable="true" discriminator-value="1000">
<composite-id>
   <key-property name="id" type="long"/>
   <key-property name="fromDate" type="imm_timestamp"/>
</composite-id>
<discriminator column="data" type="int"/>
<property name="entry"/>
<subclass name="SupclassImpl" entity-name="SupclassImplHist" discriminator-value="1">
    <property name="subId" column="sub_id" type="long"/>
</subclass>
```

```
public class SuperClassImpl implements Serializable {
private Long id;
private int version;
private String entry;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEntry() {
    return entry;
}

public void setEntry(String entry) {
    this.entry = entry;
}
```

}

```
public class SubClassImpl extends SuperClassImpl {

private Date fromDate;
private Long subId;

public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}

public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}

public Long getSubId() {
    return id;
}

public void setSubId(Long subId) {
    this.subId = subId;
}
```

}

```
/*this below code works and saves the entity*/
SuperClassImpl sci = new SuperClassImpl();
pbe.setId(109305L);
pbe.setEntry("started");
pbe.setFromDate(new Date());
HibernateUtil.currentSession().save("SuperClassImplHist", sci);


/*not working and throws exception 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set   java.lang.Long field      SubClassImpl.id to java.lang.Long*/
SubClassImpl sci = new SubClassImpl();
pbe.setId(109321L);
pbe.setSubId(2123L);
pbe.setEntry("started");
pbe.setFromDate(new Date());
HibernateUtil.currentSession().save("SubClassImplHist", sci);
```

Do you see any issues with the code or mapping? While saving the **SubClassImplHist** I get this exception

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set   java.lang.Long field SubClassImpl.id to java.lang.Long"
```

Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After half a day of code debug, found that it's indeed a bug in the hibernate version I'm using which is in hibernate version 3.0.

The issue was in the code file org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel in the method

```
public String findEntityNameByEntityClass(Class inheritenceClass) {
    return ( String ) entityNameByInheritenceClassNameMap.get( inheritenceClass.getName() );
}
```

The entityNameByInheritenceClassNameMap is holding the key with Class type.
For my problem I have no fix with the current hibernate version.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you try to save both objects with sane id '109305L'. But hibernate can't change type of the record. You can try manualy change value of 'data' column in your DB. But i strongly recomend not to follow this way and find another that not required changing type of record after creation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had added the same id for testing at two different run but now just corrected to have different id. Do you see any issues with the mapping or in the code in general?